# How do I make a folder with today's date and then copy a file to it?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to automate my day, part of which is creating a daily work folder and copying a 'Job Notes' file which I use, rename and save per job, repeat again the next day.

I found a script to create a folder based on today's date, which works, and I've obviously found examples of how to copy a file. What I'm looking for is to combine the two. I just need something basic. Here is the code I have for the folder creation. I just don't know what to add to the "copy file" action to make it use that particular directory name (based on today's date).

```psh
$location = New-Item -Path C:\Users\XXXXXXX\Documents\test -ItemType Directory -Name ("$(Get-Date -f MM_dd_yy)")

$dirname = "$((get-date).toString('MM-dd'))"
md $dirname
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, including if the above code is not the easiest way to accomplish this.

P.S. Whether a batch file or PowerShell for doing this would be fine, I am playing around learning both methods.

Answer (score 7):

You already have the location in your `$location` variable. Simply use that as the destination for `Copy-Item`:

```
$basedir = "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\test"
$today   = (Get-Date).ToString('MM_dd_yy')

$location = New-Item -Path $basedir -Type Directory -Name $today

Copy-Item 'C:\path\to\job_notes.txt' -Destination $location
```

`md` is just a shorthand (an alias for a function that calls `New-Item` with the required parameters).

Comment: That works perfectly. Followup question; What is the best way to run this? I can copy/paste into Powershell and it works just fine. Can I create a batch script out of this? I know some commands are different. If I run it through Powershell, do I just create a script in the Powershell ISE?

Comment: @MichaelWells I wouldn't recommend wrapping this in a batch script. Put it in a PowerShell script (.ps1). You can use the ISE as well as any editor you like. Note that you may need to run `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` once to enable running unsigned PowerShell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
set "location=C:\Users\XXXXXXX\Documents\test"
md "%date%"
copy "%location" "%date%"
```

Comment: Depending on the system's locale `%DATE%` might contain forward slashes, which aren't allowed characters in a folder name.